# $_GET and FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, tell if $_GET exists

Tags: php

When I run

```
if (filter_var($_GET['abc'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { ... }
```

and I don't give a `?abc=` extension to my `.php` then I get notice:

> Notice: Undefined index: abc in line...

Is there a way to bypass this notice and say if `$_GET` exists and then is `abc` then...

Thanks a lot

Comment: What prevented you from consulting the PHP manual?

Answer (score 4):

You have to test if key `abc` in GET exists, so:

```
if (isset($_GET['abc']) && filter_var($_GET['abc'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (isset($_GET['abc']) && filter_var($_GET['abc'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) { ... }
```

This way it checks if that exist and you won't get a notice , hope this help :)

Answer (score 3):

you have to check whether the index is set using `isset`

```
if (isset($_GET['abc']) && filter_var($_GET['abc'], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
```